# Match any string starting with certain characters regex MVC DataAnnotations

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I new to Regular Expressions in MVC DataAnnotations. I have a form that has a field named Option. The option must start with CA-.
I wrote the Regular Expression in different ways to validate this field and I can get it to work.
I tried all this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^CA-")]
[RegularExpression(@"/CA-/")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[C]+[A]+[-]")]
[RegularExpression(@"^CA-*")]
```

none of this work.
What is wrong with my code?
Thank you.

```
public class CA_OptionsMetadata
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^CA-", ErrorMessage = "The Option must start with CA-")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Option is Required")]
    public string Option { get; set; }
    //public string Cap_LBS { get; set; }
    //public string Cap_KG { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked!

Comment: I added an answer, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match `CA` at the beginning of a string, use

```
@"^CA-.*"
```

The main point is that the whole string should match (it is required by the `RegularExpression`), thus `.*` is important.

Regex explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `CA-` - a literal `CA-` sequence of characters
- `.*` - zero or more characters other than a newline

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It really helped.

Comment: You actually don't need the `^` since `RegularExpression` always looks for an full match: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58697576/5762332

Comment: @Magnetron Right, I removed `$`, but `^` is good to keep since it simplifies testing.