# Allow some, but not all white space in a MVC Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a Regular Expression on one of my MVC Model's properties which will allow any text, but won't allow all white space.

I've read many posts about this, but none of them are doing as I expected, so either I'm missing something very obvious or I'm not searching for the correct thing.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The Name field is required.")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The Name can only be a maximum 
    of 100 characters long.")]
[RegularExpression(@"[REGEX HERE]", 
    ErrorMessage = "The Name field can not be white space only.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

All the error messages work fine apart from last one. I've tried the following regex strings (along with many others) without success, generally when I put any white space characters (been using the space character) the error message appears, sometimes when I add more than one character:

- `@"\S+?"`
- `@"\S+"`
- `@"\S"`
- `@"\s"`

The results I expect are as follows:

- `'' < FAIL due to required attribute.`
- `'red' < PASS`
- `'red cake' < PASS`
- `'  ' < FAIL due to only white space present`

Needless to say I'm not very experienced with regexes, however this is a simple one which is really stumping me!

Comment: Do you mean like `\s*`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Wouldn't that pattern pass in the last case (All white spaces)?

Comment: How about something like `^.*\S.*$`.  That's anything at the start of the line (including nothing), followed by a non-whitespace character, followed by anything afterwards (including nothing).  It seems to work for me in a Regex test harness.  As long as you have at least one non-whitespace character, it's happy

Comment: `\S` should've worked, it means that it contains a non-whitesace character.

Comment: `\s*` fails unless there are all white spaces. `\S` passes with one character, but then will fail with any subsequent ones, white space or not.

Comment: @Flydog57 That seemed to do the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = ...)]`

Comment: @bhmahler I tried that too, but no luck there either. When I was looking at other posts on this subject a few people did mention that it didn't work as expected therefore I dismissed it and pushed forward with the regex solution.

Comment: @XN16 yeah, it appears that aspnet always interpret the regex attribute as a full string match, so when you put `\S` the aspnet read that pattern as `^\S$`, that's why it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
^.*\S.*$
```

That's...

- anything at the start of the line (including nothing),
- followed by a non-whitespace character,
- followed by anything afterwards (including nothing).

It seems to work for me in a Regex test harness. As long as you have at least one non-whitespace character, it's happy.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Now this behaviour is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

**Original Answer:**

So, I did some tests and get to the conclusion that aspnet always interpret `RegularExpression` validation as a full string match. There are no difference between both patterns `\S` and `^\S$`, it seems that the method always adds `^` at the beginning and a `$` at the end of the pattern. Wheather it's a bug or intendent behaviour, I don't know. So, that's why `\S` fails when it should work.

And the answer, as @Flydog57 put in comments is to use `.*\S.*`. Note that the `^` and `$` are not needed, as explained above

**Edit:**

It appears to be full match by design, not a bug. According to [source code, line 66](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs#L51-L68):

> We are looking for an exact match, not just a search hit.
>
> ```
> var m = Regex.Match(stringValue);
>
> // We are looking for an exact match, not just a search hit. This matches what 
> // the RegularExpressionValidator control does 
> return (m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == stringValue.Length);
> ```

Check it out [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/15488) and [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/16820) issues that I've opened for more details.