# Do Regex.Match and RegularExpression in DataAnnotations works differently?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple input string that would pass the Regex.Match but fails in the DataAnnotations . Does anyone know why ? given that the regex pattern is the same in both cases.

```
const pattern = @"^myinput\.xyz\.abc\.*";
const input = "myinput.xyz.abc.blablabla-blablabla";

const isValid = Regex.Match(request.TransactionId, pattern).Success; // ===> This will return true which is correct
```

However, in the DataAnnotations. It always fails. Here is what I have:

```
public class DummyObject
{
   [Required]
   [MaxLength(100)]
   [RegularExpression(@"^myinput\.xyz\.abc\.*")] // This will always fail, consider that the pattern that I have here is exactly what I have above.
   public string DummyString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they work differently, you need `^myinput\.xyz\.abc\..*`. You missed a `.` before `*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Could you mind explaining a bit more why I need another <code>.<code> before <code>*<code> ? Thank you

Comment: See the linked post.

Comment: Regular expressions don't work differently. [RegexExpressionAtrtribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-7.0) is not the same as `Regex.IsMatch` though. It [looks for an exact match](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5f94bffeff62f4b767a311a4505d6d40d86279d9/src/libraries/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs#L71)

Comment: The pattern you use matches a string that ends in zero or more dots, not just any character. In the first example you get `True` because there's a partial match up to `myinput.xyz.abc`. The dot doesn't match but since the pattern is `\.*`, it can be ignored. In the second case though, `RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid` checks to see that the match length is the same as the input and fails.

Comment: PS: that means you can remove `^` as the attribute's code, `m.Index == 0 && m.Length == stringValue.Length` is essentially the same as `^.....$`.

Comment: @HoangMinh check this answer of mine to the explanation. Also, you don't need the `^` at the begining: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58697576/5762332